# How do I get all types in loaded Assemblies with CoreClr?

Tags: c#, coreclr

In my application I need to get a list of all types loaded regardless of what assembly they are contained in.  For example, Project A might need to get a list of all types that implement interface `A` even if that implementation exists in project B.

In the .Net Framework I would do this by querying for all assemblies in the current app domain.

Since it seems like the concept of an app domain is gone in CoreCLR, what is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: There is no proper way, it only ever gets *core* by dropping features.  Being interested only in "loaded" types is very strange btw, defies a reasonable guess at an alternative.  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I don't understand how "get me all the types that implement the interface of X" is strange.  I need to ask the system for all types that implement a specific interface so I can set up cached mappings and be able to use reflection to create an instance and do something on that instance.  It's obviously a valid use case because the API exists for getting all types for an assembly, but that doesn't help if the class is in another assembly

Comment: I also fail to see how this is an XY problem as my question is I need to get a list of all types currently known by the system because I need to do some logic to pick out types I am interested in.

Comment: This might help you:   https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/919

Answer (score 0):

When run under DNX in RC1-Update1 (note flakey behavior when run under dotnet.exe directly):

```
var assemblies = PlatformServices.Default.LibraryManager.GetLibraries().SelectMany(l => l.Assemblies.Select(an =>
{
try
{ return Assembly.Load(an); }
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException)
{ return null; }
})).Where(a => (object)a != null);
```

For a real workd example, see [AssemblyLoaderContainerContext.cs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/textmetal/main/master/src/TextMetal.Middleware.Solder/Runtime/AssemblyLoaderContainerContext.cs) in my TextMteal project on GitHub.

It is also worth noting that a naive attempt to "get me all the types that implement the interface of X" would fail to look at interface maps of types. Lucky for Core CLR, TypeInfo exposes ImplementedInterfaces which greatly simplifies this task versus the previos .NET full frameworks (prior to System.Runtime).